# handling null values from api response using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently , I came to know about the null safety in kotlin . In previous java language I struggled to handle unfortunate null values. For this I have to null check  and get the values from list of data.

Example

```
 if (sampledata.getId() !=null)

     {
          textview.setText(sampledata.getId());
     }
```

It becomes boilerplate code by checking null check on each values .  Is there efficient solution to handle in kotlin? Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

```
    var id:Int ?=null // into your pojo class..
```

then after..

```
        var res=ResData()
    res?.id
    textview.text=res?.id
```

Comment: I am new to kotlin.  In this code if the value null means what happens ?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) construction with safe call ([`?`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)):

```
sampledata.getId()?.let { textview.text = it }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access same thing just by placing **null-coalscing operators** in kotlin.

Check [Null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) here.